# Combine single date record with multiple time slot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Below are the tables used to populate the event slots.

Event Table

```
EventID | Name         | EventDateTime(SMALLDATETIME)       
--------+--------------+-----------------------------
   1    | Tech Session | 2014-02-21 00:00:00 
   2    | Job Session  | 2014-02-25 00:00:00
```

Slots Table

```
SlotID  | EventId| StartTime(TIME)  |  EndTime(TIME)   |
--------+--------------+---------------------+----------
   1    | 1      | 10:00:00.0000000 | 10:45:00.0000000 |
   2    | 1      | 10:45:00.0000000 | 11:30:00.0000000 |
   3    | 1      | 11:30:00.0000000 | 12:15:00.0000000 |
   4    | 1      | 12:15:00.0000000 | 13:00:00.0000000 |
   5    | 2      | 11:00:00.0000000 | 13:00:00.0000000 |
   6    | 2      | 13:00:00.0000000 | 15:00:00.0000000 |
```

Expected AvailableSlots: **How do i query the to get the below result?**

```
Name         | StartDateTime       |  EndDateTime        |
--------+--------------+---------------------+------------
Tech Session | 2014-02-21 10:00:00 | 2014-02-21 10:45:00 |
Tech Session | 2014-02-21 10:45:00 | 2014-02-21 11:30:00 |
Tech Session | 2014-02-21 11:30:00 | 2014-02-21 12:15:00 |
Tech Session | 2014-02-21 12:15:00 | 2014-02-21 13:00:00 |
Job Session  | 2014-02-25 11:00:00 | 2014-02-21 13:00:00 |
Job Session  | 2014-02-25 13:00:00 | 2014-02-21 15:00:00 |
```

Comment: What is the data type of column StartTime and EndTime?

Comment: @TechDo, its `TIME`. Edited my question

Comment: I would have thought you'd want the first start time and the last end time for contiguous slots, ie `Tech Session | 2014-02-21 10:00:00 | 2014-02-21 13:00:00`

Comment: @Bohemian, 4 slots and 45 mins each for tech session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, StartTime), EventDateTime) StartDateTime, 
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, EndTime), EventDateTime) EndDateTime
FROM EventTable a INNER JOIN SlotsTable b ON a.EventId=b.EventId
```

Comment: Great. But could you please look into this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe27d/1 I hard coded EventID=1 in temp table , I want to populate for all events mentioned.

Comment: @Billa Please check a solution without using temporary table. Solution obtained using multiple CTE. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe27d/39

Comment: The CTE `T` is missing slots for second event. I tried removing `where DATEADD(SECOND,DURATION, EndTime)<=  EndTime1` but now i get `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion`. I want to load all the slots for all events in that

Comment: I think CTE `RepeatingEvents` is not returning any value for EventID=2.

Comment: CTE `T` itself not returning any rows for EventID=2. Could you please check it

Comment: Now everything works :) My mistake, my INSERT statement for `RepeatDayOfWeek` was wrong, [New Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bcaf0/1) You saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider the posibility of dayshift between [StartTime] and [EndTime].
That would render my answer invalid

```
SELECT a.name, 
       a.eventdatetime + b.starttime StartDateTime, 
       a.eventdatetime + b.endtime   Enddatetime 
FROM   event a 
       JOIN slot b 
         ON a.eventid = b.eventid
```

Comment: This [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe27d/1) is what I am trying to make it work. But I restricted for only one record `SELECT @CURRENT_TIME = StartTime, @START_TIME = StartTime, @END_TIME = EndTime, @DURATION = Duration FROM [Event] where EventID = 1`. Is there a way to load all start & end time for all events in temp table? Could you please help?